# Why is $\lambda x.\lambda y. x y$ $\alpha$-equivalent to $\lambda x. \lambda y. yx$?

Tags: computer-science, lambda-calculus

Why is $\lambda x.\lambda y. x y$  $\alpha$-equivalent to $\lambda x. \lambda y. yx$?
Can we prove it by strict steps based on the definition of $\alpha$-equivalence in the $\lambda$-calculus?

Comment: What happens if you switch the labels of x and y? What happens if switch the order of the lambda terms?

Answer (score 1):

$\lambda x. \lambda y.x(y)$ is NOT $\alpha$-equivalent to $\lambda x.\lambda y.y(x)$.

Indeed, suppose for the sake of contradiction that $\lambda x. \lambda y.x(y)$ is $\alpha$-equivalent to $\lambda x.\lambda y.y(x)$. Then,
\begin{align}
 \lambda x. \lambda y.x(y) &=_\beta \lambda x.\lambda y.y(x) &\text{because $\beta$-conversion contains $\alpha$-equivalence} \\
(\lambda x. \lambda y.x(y))z_1z_2 &=_\beta (\lambda x.\lambda y.y(x))z_1z_2 &\text{by contextual closure}  \\
 z_1z_2 &=_\beta z_2z_1 &\text{by $\beta$-conversion}
\end{align}
But $z_1z_2$ and $z_2z_1$ are normal and syntactically different terms, so $z_1z_2 \neq_\beta z_2z_1$. Contradiction.